# split a dataframe column by regular expression on characters separated by a "."

Tags: regex, r, plyr

In R, I have the following dataframe:

```
     Name     Category
1    Beans    1.12.5
2    Pears    5.7.9
3    Eggs     10.6.5
```

What I would like to have is the following:

```
     Name     Cat1    Cat2    Cat3
1    Beans    1       12      5
2    Pears    5       7       9
3    Eggs     10      6       5
```

Ideally some expression built inside plyr would be nice...

I will investigate on my side but as searching this might take me a lot of time I was just wondering if some of you do have some hints to perform this...

Comment: Do you expect every item to have exactly three categories?

Comment: You are right I should have been more precise with this, some answers will have less or more than 3 categories, with a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 5!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've written a function `concat.split` (a "family" of functions, actually) as part of my `splitstackshape` package for dealing with these types of problems:

```
# install.packages("splitstackshape")
library(splitstackshape)
concat.split(mydf, "Category", ".", drop=TRUE)
#    Name Category_1 Category_2 Category_3
# 1 Beans          1         12          5
# 2 Pears          5          7          9
# 3  Eggs         10          6          5
```

It also works nicely on "unbalanced" data.

```
dat <- data.frame(Name = c("Beans", "Pears", "Eggs"), 
                  Category = c("1.12.5", "5.7.9.8", "10.6.5.7.7"))
concat.split(dat, "Category", ".", drop = TRUE)
#    Name Category_1 Category_2 Category_3 Category_4 Category_5
# 1 Beans          1         12          5         NA         NA
# 2 Pears          5          7          9          8         NA
# 3  Eggs         10          6          5          7          7
```

---

Because "long" or "molten" data are often required in these types of situations, the `concat.split.multiple` function has a "long" argument too:

```
concat.split.multiple(dat, "Category", ".", direction = "long")
#     Name time Category
# 1  Beans    1        1
# 2  Pears    1        5
# 3   Eggs    1       10
# 4  Beans    2       12
# 5  Pears    2        7
# 6   Eggs    2        6
# 7  Beans    3        5
# 8  Pears    3        9
# 9   Eggs    3        5
# 10 Beans    4       NA
# 11 Pears    4        8
# 12  Eggs    4        7
# 13 Beans    5       NA
# 14 Pears    5       NA
# 15  Eggs    5        7
```

Comment: And I see that it deals with the case of unequal numbers of values.

Comment: The first day in my new splitstackshape-concat.split.multiple-life! The future is bright! +1

Comment: @Henrik, bug-reports/feature enhancements [here](https://github.com/mrdwab/splitstackshape/issues?state=open) please :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a consistent number of categories, then this will work:

```
#recreate your data first:
dat <- data.frame(Name = c("Beans", "Pears", "Eggs"), Category = c("1.12.5", 
"5.7.9", "10.6.5"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

spl <- strsplit(dat$Category,"\\.")
len <- sapply(spl,length)
dat[paste0("cat",1:max(len))] <- t(sapply(spl,as.numeric))
```

Result:

```
dat
   Name Category cat1 cat2 cat3
1 Beans   1.12.5    1   12    5
2 Pears    5.7.9    5    7    9
3  Eggs   10.6.5   10    6    5
```

If you have differing numbers of separated values, then this should account for it:

```
#example unbalanced data
dat <- data.frame(Name = c("Beans", "Pears", "Eggs"), Category = c("1.12.5", 
"5.7.9", "10.6.5"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dat$Category[2] <- "5.7"

spl <- strsplit(dat$Category,"\\.")
len <- sapply(spl,length)
spl <- Map(function(x,y) c(x,rep(NA,max(len)-y)), spl, len)

dat[paste0("cat",1:max(len))] <- t(sapply(spl,as.numeric))
```

Result:

```
   Name Category cat1 cat2 cat3
1 Beans   1.12.5    1   12    5
2 Pears      5.7    5    7   NA
3  Eggs   10.6.5   10    6    5
```

Answer (score 2):

The qdap package has the `colsplit2df` for just these sort of situations:

```
#recreate your data first:
dat <- data.frame(Name = c("Beans", "Pears", "Eggs"), Category = c("1.12.5", 
"5.7.9", "10.6.5"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(qdap)
colsplit2df(dat, 2, paste0("cat", 1:3))

## > colsplit2df(dat, 2, paste0("cat", 1:3))
##    Name cat1 cat2 cat3
## 1 Beans    1   12    5
## 2 Pears    5    7    9
## 3  Eggs   10    6    5
```